# How to show a jPanel in a jFrame when pressing a menuItem

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, jpanel, jdialog

I am using JAVA Netbeans. I already have my menu, which is the first photo:

[image]

When I press one of my menuItems it opens a new jDialog which contains something like this:

[image]

I want that when I press the menu Item, all the components that I have on the jDialog open in the jFrame... so they can adjust to the principal frame. And I want this to happen to every menuItem that I have, so when I press another menuItem it replaces all the information that I have on the jFrame at the moment or if possible open some kind of tabs?

Comment: First, I'd not bother with the dialog, I'd just add the panel directly to the frame to start with, seems like an unnecessary step to me. Second, I'd have a look at [How to use Actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), it will help simplify the process. Third, depending on the complexity of the overall app, I might consider using a `CardLayout`. Have a look at [How to use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: Another option might be to use a `JTabbedPane`

Answer (score 2):

Any solution is going to require some form of Model-View-Controller. This will help facilitate the functionality while de-coupling the API.

First, I'd start by having a look at [How to use Actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html). These are self contained units of work which can easily be applied to buttons and key bindings and provide a bases for re-usable snippets of code.

For example, we could define a very simple `Action` which simply managers the interaction of the view to the controller to facilitate the switching of views:

```
public abstract class AbstractManagerAction extends AbstractAction {

    private Controller controller;
    private JPanel panel;

    public AbstractManagerAction(Controller manager, JPanel panel) {
        this.controller = manager;
        this.panel = panel;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        controller.show(panel);
    }

}
```

The `Action` doesn't care "how" the `Controller` works, only that when it passes the view to it, the view will be shown on the screen, so the underlying implementation of the controller change change, but, because of the contract established by the API, the `Action` doesn't need to change.

Now, you could have a `Controller` which deals with creating the `JDialog` and a `Controller` which manages the `JFrame`, chaining them together as required.

Okay, but how does that actually make your life any simpler I hear you ask?

Well, let's assume you have a view something like this...

```
public class SomeOptionsPane extends JPanel {

    public SomeOptionsPane() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(new JLabel("Some options"));
    }

}
```

In order to present it on the screen, we need to start by defining it's own `Action`...

```
public class SomeOptionsAction extends AbstractManagerAction {
    public SomeOptionsAction(Controller controller) {
        super(controller, new SomeOptionsPane());
        putValue(NAME, "Some options");
    }
}
```

This allows us to abstract the common functionality (presented above) but allows for customisation (in this case I've only defined the text which will be displayed) for the view itself. You can also define a bunch of other properties, but for brevity, I've skipped that step.

Now, when I want to add the option to the `JMenuBar`/`JMenu`, I just need to create an instance of the `Action`...

```
JMenu options = new JMenu("Options");
options.add(new SomeOptionsAction(controller));
```

Simple.  Now, when the `Action` is triggered, it will call the `Controller`s `show` method and pass the instance of the view to it!  Magic!

Overall, you could also consider using a `CardLayout` or `JTabbedPane` to further improve the user experience, depending on how complex the UI is in general.  See [How to use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) and [How to Use Tabbed Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) for more details.

And, because I know you're not going to be satisfied until you see it running, the basic code I used to test the idea..

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                Controller manager = new Controller() {
                    @Override
                    public void show(JPanel pane) {
                        frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
                        frame.getContentPane().add(pane);
                        frame.getContentPane().revalidate();
                        frame.getContentPane().repaint();
                    }
                };

                JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
                JMenu options = new JMenu("Options");
                menuBar.add(options);
                options.add(new SomeOptionsAction(manager));
                options.add(new SomeOtherOptionsAction(manager));
                frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

                frame.setSize(200, 200);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface Controller {

        public void show(JPanel pane);
    }

    public abstract class AbstractManagerAction extends AbstractAction {

        private Controller controller;
        private JPanel panel;

        public AbstractManagerAction(Controller controller, JPanel panel) {
            this.controller = controller;
            this.panel = panel;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            controller.show(panel);
        }

    }

    public class SomeOptionsAction extends AbstractManagerAction {

        public SomeOptionsAction(Controller controller) {
            super(controller, new SomeOptionsPane());
            putValue(NAME, "Some options");
        }
    }

    public class SomeOptionsPane extends JPanel {

        public SomeOptionsPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(new JLabel("Some options"));
        }

    }

    public class SomeOtherOptionsAction extends AbstractManagerAction {

        public SomeOtherOptionsAction(Controller manager) {
            super(manager, new SomeOtherOptionsPane());
            putValue(NAME, "Some other options");
        }
    }

    public class SomeOtherOptionsPane extends JPanel {

        public SomeOtherOptionsPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(new JLabel("Some other options"));
        }

    }
}
```

Now, before I get roasted, I know this is not a "traditional" MVC, but neither is Swing, so I've focused on provide a decoupled solution